# Export Filtered/Searched Data into Excel, from an Angular datatable

Tags: angularjs, excel, datatable, export-to-excel, angular-datatables

I am trying to export the data in my angular data table into an Excel sheet. I am successful in exporting the whole Json object into an Excel sheet.

What I am looking for is, to get the searched/filtered data only to be exported into Excel, if the search is empty then export all the data.

For the reference let me show you how my code is

This is my Controller

```
userService.getUserList( function(response) {
    if (response.status === 200) {
        vm.users = response.data.userDetails;
        return;
    }
    if (response.status === 400) {
        return toastr.error(response.data.exception);
    }

});


vm.exportData = function() {

    vm.listOfUsers = angular.copy(vm.users);

    vm.filteredData = _.map(vm.listOfUsers, function(data){
        var status = (data.isActive==true)?'Active':'In-Active';

        var users = {'Name': data.fullName, 'Email': data.email, 'Designation': data.designation, 'Company Name': data.companyName,'Status':status}
        return users;
    });

    alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("download.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [vm.filteredData]);
}
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="table-toolbar">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="btn-group">
                   <button id="sample_editable_1_new" class="btn sbold green" ng-click="vm.exportData()">Export As Excel</button>
               </div>
          </div>                                    
     </div>
</div>

<div class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" datatable="ng" id="sample_1">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Sl. No. </th>
                <th> Name </th>
                <th> Email </th>
                <th> Designation </th>                                                                                                 
                <th> Company Name </th>                                                 
                <th> Status </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in vm.users">
                  <td> {{$index+1}} </td>
                  <td> {{user.fullName}} </td>
                 <td> {{user.email}} </td>
                   <td> {{user.designation}} </td>                                                                                                
                  <td> {{user.companyName}} </td>                                                 
                  <td>{{user.isActive === true? "Active" : "In-Active" }} 
                  </td> 
              </tr>
           </tbody>
  </table>
```

As datatables has inbuilt functionality of searching, When User type something, it starts searching, So when user searches and then click on Export Button, then I want to pass only those datas related to the search query, so that only those data are exported into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,

Rather than printing the Data, I Printed the whole HTML table, So whatever search, or sort order. the same data that will be in the HTML will be exported.

only Change is, I added userDatatable class to the table in html and changed the alasql query  as follows

```
 alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("download.xlsx",{headers:true}) \
                FROM HTML(".userDatatable")');
```

This fixed MY issue.Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps in order:

1. First put your ID in the HTML table tag.
2. Then inject the Excel service into the constructor and write the
   Excel function.
3. Then write the Excel service.

HTML:

```
<table id="ExampleTable">
 .
 .
 .
</table>
```

COMPONENT.TS:

```
 constructor(private excel: ExcelService) {}
```

AND

```
 exportExcel(): void {
   this.excel.exportExcel('ExampleTable');
 }
```

ExcelService:

```
  public exportExcel(tableId: string, name?: string): void {
    const timeSpan = new Date().toISOString();
    const prefix = name || 'ExportResult';
    const fileName = `${prefix}-${timeSpan}`;
    const targetTableElm = document.getElementById(tableId);
    const wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(targetTableElm, { sheet: prefix } as 
 XLSX.Table2SheetOpts);
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, `${fileName}.xlsx`);
  }
```